# How can i convert Dollar into cents on stripes charge.php page?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**This is my code**

**getting price from last page**

```
$Voucher_value=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Voucher_value']);

 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'amount'   => $Voucher_value,
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'receipt_email' => $email
    ));
    $chargeAmount=$charge['amount'];
    $Custcurrency=$charge['currency'];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're always dealing with US dollars, or another currency with 2 decimal points, you can simply multiply by 100 and truncate the results to an integer:

```
$amount = intval($Voucher_value * 100);
```